# How can I combine multiple raster datasets with multiple unique values in ArcMap 10.6?

Tags: arcmap, geotiff-tiff, combine

I have to combine plenty of raster datasets. The problem is there are to many unique values. I guess that’s because there are layers where areas have geometry and there are not geometry on the other layers on the same areas. So, I have to combine raster layers with a little bit different geometry. I tried Combine function but it did not work because of the unique values. The resolution is the same on all layers.

The attribute table should look like something like this:

[image]

Here is an example for two layers:

[image] [image]

Comment: How do you want to combine your raster datasets? Should they be added together, use one layer first, or have unique values for each combination? As per the ESRI help file with this, using anything other than the GRID format limits you to 65,536 unique image values which may be part of your problem.

Comment: I am a bit unclear about your ultimate objective. What do you want to do with the data once it is in the table? What does "record_x" represent?

Comment: They should have unique values for each combination.
Record_x present the id.